# How to use WITH in a better way to parametrise a date

Tags: postgresql, cte

I love to use CTEs to create nice and clear queries. However, I'm pretty sure the query I created is really inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this and keep things clear ?

```sql
with first_date as (
    -- selecting just 1 date 
    --    namely:  1 full year ago
    select (extract(year from current_date - interval '1 year')||'-01-01' )::date as date
    )
, last_date as (
    select date from star.dim_date where current_cal_day='Current'
)
, total_active_customers_ps_day as(
  select
        dd.date
        , dd.is_first_day_in_month
        , dd.is_last_day_in_month   
        , count(dc.id) as total_customers
    from first_date, last_date,
        star.dim_date dd
        -- join with dim_client, using first_subscription_start_date & last_subscription_end_date
        --   to get the ids of just the active clients 
        join star.dim_client dc on dd.date 
            between dc.first_subscription_start_date and coalesce(dc.last_subscription_end_date::date, '3000-01-01') 
            and dc.created <= dd.date
            and dc.first_subscription_start_date >= dc.created::date
    where 
        dd.date >= first_date.date
        and dd.date <= last_date.date
    group by 
        dd.date
        , dd.is_first_day_in_month 
        , dd.is_last_day_in_month   
)
select * from total_active_customers_ps_day ;
```

I think I'm causing some cartesian joins, since this query is far more efficient

```
with total_active_customers_ps_day as(
  select
        dd.date
        , dd.is_first_day_in_month
        , dd.is_last_day_in_month   
        , count(dc.id) as total_customers
    from 
        star.dim_date dd
        -- join with dim_client, using first_subscription_start_date & last_subscription_end_date
        --   to get the ids of just the active clients 
        join star.dim_client dc on dd.date 
            between dc.first_subscription_start_date and coalesce(dc.last_subscription_end_date::date, '3000-01-01') 
            and dc.created <= dd.date
            and dc.first_subscription_start_date >= dc.created::date
    where 
        dd.date >=  (extract(year from current_date - interval '1 year')||'-01-01' )::date
        and dd.date <= (select date from star.dim_date where current_cal_day='Current')
    group by 
        dd.date
        , dd.is_first_day_in_month 
        , dd.is_last_day_in_month   
)
select * from total_active_customers_ps_day ;
```

What's the better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to fetch the end date, you can calculate it once in a common table expression (CTE) at the beginning of the query, similar to what you did for the start date. This reduces the complexity of the `WHERE` clause and potentially makes the query more efficient.

There is indeed a Cartesian join between the `star.dim_date` table and the CTEs `start_date` and `end_date`. This could potentially lead to performance issues, especially if the `star.dim_date` table contains a large number of rows.

To avoid the Cartesian join and make the query more efficient, you can use a single CTE to calculate both the start and end dates and then join this CTE with the `star.dim_date` table.

Also I've used the `DATE_TRUNC` function to calculate the start date as one year ago from the current date, which can make the query more intuitive.

```
WITH date_range AS (
    SELECT
        (DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 YEAR')::DATE AS start_date,
        DATE_TRUNC('DAY', CURRENT_DATE) AS end_date
),

total_active_customers_per_day AS (
    SELECT
        dd.date,
        dd.is_first_day_in_month,
        dd.is_last_day_in_month,
        COUNT(dc.id) AS total_customers
    FROM
        star.dim_date dd
    JOIN
        star.dim_client dc ON dd.date BETWEEN dc.first_subscription_start_date AND COALESCE(dc.last_subscription_end_date::DATE, '3000-01-01')
            AND dc.created <= dd.date
            AND dc.first_subscription_start_date >= dc.created::DATE
    JOIN
        date_range ON dd.date BETWEEN date_range.start_date AND date_range.end_date
    GROUP BY
        dd.date,
        dd.is_first_day_in_month,
        dd.is_last_day_in_month
)

SELECT * FROM total_active_customers_per_day;
```

Ensure that the columns used in the `JOIN` conditions and the `WHERE` clause are properly indexed. In your case, indexing columns like `dd.date`, `dc.first_subscription_start_date`, and `dc.last_subscription_end_date` can significantly improve query performance.